# Authenticating HTTP request through URL

Tags: authentication, url, httprequest, basic-authentication, http-authentication

I need to retrieve the page https://server_addr:8080/v1/profile/+18017629094. The authentication credentials are `username=+18016364708` and `password=Wmsb7Ii00MHyqLAKlyIl+e0n`.

I tried `https://server_addr:8080/v1/profile/+18017629094?login=+18016364708&password=Wmsb7Ii00MHyqLAKlyIl+e0n` and a bunch of other patterns like `https://+18017629094:Wmsb7Ii00MHyqLAKlyIl+e0n@server_addr:8080/v1/profile/+18017629094`. It still asks for the credentials.

How can I authenticate through the URL itself?

Comment: Are you able to reach the server at all? When I go to a command line and run `ping signal.cs.byu.edu` it says `Destination Host Unreachable`. Is it possible this server is only accessible internally?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use of the format `"user:password"` in the userinfo field is deprecated by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). Some modern browsers therefore no longer support URL encoding of basic access credentials. Applications should not render as clear text any data after the first colon (":") character found within a userinfo sub component. A password appearing within the userinfo component is deprecated and considered an error or simply ignored.
It would be safer to utilise the HTTP Authorization request header containing the credentials to authenticate a user agent with a server as

```
Authorization: <type> <credentials>
```

For example, `Authorization: Basic YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l`

Or, alternatively, as you have already tried, you can append the user credentials to the URL as query parameters, but it will require you to implement your own user authentication logic on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Since your username and password contain reserved characters like `+`, have you tried URL encoding your username and password in the URL?

So in your case, `+18017629094` becomes `%2B18017629094` and `Wmsb7Ii00MHyqLAKlyIl+e0n` becomes `Wmsb7Ii00MHyqLAKlyIl%2Be0n`.